# sed/awk/vim: how to replace variable in a function call

Tags: awk, vim, sed

I have this piece of fortran code (there are 6   before `call` and 5   before `&`):

```
           call mpi_send( v(1), nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
          &               prev, myid-1, comm, ierr )
```

And I am looking for a way to extract `nx` and `myid-1` to replace them by respectively `cnt` and `tag` (ideally aligned with `call` just above) like so:

```
           cnt = nx
           tag = myid-1
           call mpi_send( v(1), cnt, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
          &               prev, tag, comm, ierr )
```

`cnt` (or `nx`) is always the second argument of `mpi_send`. `tag` (or `myid-1`) is always the 5th argument of `mpi_send`.

I understand I have to play with the `s` substitute `sed` option, combined with capture, and "insert above" command... This may/could look like:

```
  sed -i '/mpi_send(.*, \(.*\), .*&.*, \(.*\)/{
s//\1/
i\
      cnt = \1
      tag = \2 
}' file.f
```

... Which doesn't work: I can't get a way to get that together.

**EDIT**

Ideally looking for a solution that could handle all cases like :

```
           call mpi_recv( mv_buf, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, prev, myid,
          &               comm, status, ierr )
```

That should be replaced by

```
           cnt = nx
           tag = myid
           call mpi_recv( mv_buf, cnt, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, prev, tag,
          &               comm, status, ierr )
```

**EDIT**

Ideally need to handle lots of other slightly different changing cases (where patterns to replace may change) and where indentation may change in `if` blocks (6   before `if`, and so, more than 6 before `call mpi_send`).

```
         if ( myid .lt. nprocs-1 ) then
            call mpi_send( v((np-1)*nx+1), nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
        &                  next, myid+1, comm, ierr )
          endif
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: How are `nx` and `myid-1` determined? Are their  names fixed, or their positons fixed?

Comment: position fixed: see updated description above

Comment: But function name is different this time. Is that intended to be run on all functions independent of their names?

Comment: I thought I could have a regexp per function name: looks already complicated enough!... :D Anyway, I'd like to get something that works for one function, so that, I can adapt it to other functions according to needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ugly `sed` command should work for all functions whose names start with `mpi_`:

```
sed -i.orig '/^ *call mpi_.*(/{
N
s/\( *\)\([^,]*,\)\([^,]*\),\(\([^,]*,\)\{2\}\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\1cnt = \3\
\1tag = \6\
\1\2 cnt,\4 tag\7/
}' file.f
```

Comment: Waow!... Seems to work! Can you explain the black magic behind? :D

Comment: I get misalignment (`cnt` and `tag` offseted w.r.t `call mpi_`). Could be possible get alignment too?

Comment: @FGHP I see 6 blanks before `cnt` and `tag` on my computer. Isn't that correct? How many blanks should there have been?

Comment: On target code, `mpi_send/recv` may be in `if` statements: in theses case, `call mpi_` has more than 6 ` ` behind (say 8 or 9 depending on the way the code is written). I'll add an EDIT section to the initial question

Comment: I think I get it and updated the answer.

Comment: Man! Working! Can you explain the logic? if I need to adapt this to other (possibly more complex) mpi functions, I need first to understand this one

Comment: @FGHP Not much magic here. Two points are important: 1) The `N` command appends the next line (here, the line whose first non-blank character is `&`) to the pattern space. 2) A backslash (``\``) immediately followed by a newline will embed a newline into the "replace" (right hand side) portion of `s` command of `sed`. Most `sed`s permit ``\n`` to be typed directly into the RHS of `s` command, which is then converted to a newline on output. The rest are just substitutions of backreferences (``\1``, ``\2``, ``\3`` ...).

Answer (score 0):

In awk it would be something like this:

```
awk '/mpi_send/ {process=1; print "cnt = nx\ntag = myid-1"; gsub(/nx/, "cnt");print; next} process {gsub("myid-1", "tag"); print; process = 0; next} 1' file.f
```

For example if file.f contained:

```
call mpi_send( v(1), nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
        &               prev, myid-1, comm, ierr )
call something_else( v(1), nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
        &               prev, myid-1, comm, ierr )
```

it would return:

```
$ awk '/mpi_send/ {process=1; print "cnt = nx\ntag = myid-1"; gsub(/nx/, "cnt");print; next} process {gsub("myid-1", "tag"); print; process = 0; next} 1' file.f
cnt = nx
tag = myid-1
call mpi_send( v(1), cnt, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
        &               prev, tag, comm, ierr )
call something_else( v(1), nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,
        &               prev, myid-1, comm, ierr )
```

It can be slightly improved to use more future-proof regexes but
should work in most cases.

Comment: I get the idea, but, `cnt`/`tag` may not always be `nx`/`myid-1`: I updated the initial description of the question.